# Like button "Post to Facebook" not submitting

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-social-plugins

I'm seeing some complicated, not-documented behavior with the like button on a couple of sites I manage.

Here are two examples:

> http://action.anthonybrown.com/secondterm/thanks/
>
> http://handsoffwomenshealth.com/thanks/

In both cases these are signup form "thank you" pages where the intended purpose is to "like" the actual main landing page.

In both cases, users can click the like button and the like is actually registered back to Facebook.

In both cases, the popup "flyout" to allow users to post comments / statuses shows properly. However, when you fill out a comment and click "Post to Facebook," nothing happens. Your comment is not posted to Facebook and the dialog does not disappear.

A comment to a bug report here:

> See Comment 1

...suggests that this is expected behavior when links generated by the like button are "protected" by Facebook and shown with a "please be careful" interstitial when clicked on by a user in facebook.com.

When I use the like button myself, links in my activity posts about both pages do go through this "protection" mechanism:

> See Comment 2

To be clear, I'm not actually certain that the failure to post a comment is related to the "please be careful" warning, but it does seem to be correlated.

Google, Facebook, and Stack Exchange searches all suggest that this issue is reasonably common, but provide almost zero insight into why it's happening and how it can be mitigated.

Any help in understanding/solving the issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/457650447588988?fb_comment_id=fbc_10151329701383098_29484417_10151525761183098#u_0_1

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/toddplants/activity/10100635035780001

https://www.facebook.com/toddplants/activity/10100635006528621

(Both of those should be public.)